# Python only has one instance of object's dictonary when run concurrently

Tags: python, multithreading

When running threads using the threading and Queue libraries, I am creating an object in the threads run() function. Let's say that the class initiates like so:

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self, dictionary={}):
        self.dict = dictionary
```

When I try to access the dictionary in different threads, it seems like Python is only creating one instance of the dictionary. Here is the Thread class. I started two of these:

```
class ThreadTest(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        while True:
            // interact with Queue items
            obj = Test()
            print "%s - %s" % (self.name, id(obj.dict))
            queue.task_done()
```

And the output:

```
Thread-1 - 19219616
Thread-2 - 19219616
```

This is really confusing because the Test class is created twice, but it is sharing the same dictionary.

Is there a way to create a new instance of dictionary in this case?

Comment: This has been answered time and again, and yes, you can overcome it by not using a mutable default argument.

Comment: Okay. I didn't realize the issue was caused by the default argument. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default arguments are only evaluated once, when the `def` line is encountered. Therefore, your default argument `dictionary={}` is shared between all instances.

Use `dictionary=None` instead, and

```
if dictionary is None:
    self.dict = {}
else:
    self.dict = dictionary
```

to create a new instance each time.